# Генератор пароля с классами Python

Tags: python-3.x

Я пытался написать генератор пароля. И мне надо чтобы этот код содержал следующие пункты:

1. ООП
2. Lambda
3. Рекурсия
4. list comprehension
5. SOLID принцип(Обязательно первый и второй принцип)
   Это мой код:

   ```
    import random,string

    class Passw():
      generators = [lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase),
      lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase),
      lambda: random.choice(string.digits),
      lambda: random.choice(string.punctuation)]
      replacements = {"e":"3","i":"1","a":"@","o":"0","b":"6","m":"w","s":"$","8":"&","l":"L","t":"7","q":"o|","w":"W","r":"R","p":"|o"}
      def __init__(self,num):   #length of password
        self.n = num
      def gen_password(self):
        password="".join([replacements[x] if x in replacements else x for x in gen_passwd(n-1)])[:n]

     pasw=Passw(int(input()))
     pasw.gen_password()
   ```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Соорудить этот генератор с использованием перечисленных Вами требований не сложно. Сложнее понять принцип шифрования который Вы пытаетесь использовать.

Comment: Что должен делать генератор? Какие к нему требования?

Comment: Он должен принимать один аргумент это длина и взять символы из ламбды и составить пароль

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код заработает если его поправить примерно так:

```
import random,string

class Passw:
    generators = [lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase),
                  lambda: random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase),
                  lambda: random.choice(string.digits),
                  lambda: random.choice(string.punctuation)]
    replacements = {"e":"3","i":"1","a":"@","o":"0","b":"6","m":"w","s":"$","8":"&","l":"L",
                    "t":"7","q":"o|","w":"W","r":"R","p":"|o"}

    def __init__(self, num):   #length of password
        self.num = num
        self.password = self.get_password()

    def gen_password(self, n):
        if n==0: return ''
        return Passw.generators[random.randint(0,3)]() + self.gen_password(n-1)

    def get_password(self):
        return ''.join([Passw.replacements.get(i, i) for i in self.gen_password(self.num)])

pasw=Passw(int(input()))
pasw.password
'''
5
'[KEQj'
```